# Manually implement structured binding in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14

Would it be possible to implement C++17 structured bindings using C++14?
I am targetting a simple proof of concept with the following syntax:

```cpp
int a,b;
(a,b)=std::tuple<int,int>(4,2);
```

The way I imagined it is :

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
operator=(operator()(T a, U b), std::tuple<T,U>(x,y))
```

So the `=` receives a "tied tuple" left and assigns the right to it.

Would this even be possible? - Is it implementable with C++14, or does lexing/parsing need to take place in the background to enable it?

**EDIT** Is this possible without using `std::tie`, but using the (a,b) syntax?

Comment: `(a,b) = whatever` isn't a structured binding, because it doesn't define `a` or `b`, you need them to already exist. That's why it's a language feature and not a library feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. This even already exists in the standard library as [`std::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(4, 2);
```

Note that this *only* works for tuples on the right-hand side. You could fairly straightforwardly extend this to work for raw arrays. But getting it to work for aggregates is much harder - without extra language support you'd need [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) for that.

---

If you literally want:

```
(a, b) = std::make_tuple(4, 2);
```

to work, then the only way to do that is basically trash all the rest of the code you have by adding a global `operator,()` that does `std::tie()` for you:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto operator,(T& t, U& u) { return std::tie(t, u); }

template <typename... T, typename U>
auto operator,(std::tuple<T&...> t, U& u) { return std::tuple_cat(t, std::tie(u)); }
```

So that:

```
(a, b) = std::make_tuple(4, 2);
```

itself transforms into:

```
std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(4, 2);
```

But like... don't do that.

Comment: sorry, I mean without using std::tie. Is the sytax `(a,b)=std::tuple<>` possible?

Comment: @MihaiGalos no unless `a` or `b` are user-defined types and there is an overloaded `operator ,` for them.

Comment: "*But like... don't do that*" - Giga **+1** on that. I fear even trying to imagine how much code it could break...